# Integral as limit of riemann sum

Tags: riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I do not quite see how $$\sum_{k=0}^mf\left(\frac{k}{m}\right) \approx\int_0^mf\left(\frac{x}{m}\right)dx\tag{1}$$ immediately.

Though I know the for the following Riemann sum.

$$m\sum_{k=0}^mf\left(\frac{k}{m}\right)\frac{1}{m}\to m\int_0^1 f(x)dx$$ and by making the substitution $x=\frac{y}{m}$ and changing the variable name, I get $$\int_0^mf\left(\frac{x}{m}\right)dx$$

Edit:

(1) is an approximation given in my book. I would like a word explanation why it is correct without going through the steps I gave

Comment: you dont need to divide by $m$ inside $f$, by example you can set $g(x):=f(x/m)$ and the resultant expressions are simpler. Moreover: the LHS doesn't seems a Riemann sum because there is no length, that depends on $m$, associated to each value that $f$ takes

Comment: maybe the expression you want is the [Euler-MacLaurin sum formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), but it isn't related to Riemann sums

Comment: But I could show it using Riemann sums. There should be a simple 1 or 2 sentence explanation why the approximation works.

Comment: and how you shows it using Riemann sums? What you can get using Riemann sums is that $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac1m\sum_{k=0}^m f(k/m)=\int_0^1 f(x) dx=\frac1m\int_0^m f(x/m) dx$$ what is different that say $$\sum_{k=0}^m f(k/m)\approx\int_0^m f(x/m) dx$$

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^mf(k/m)=m\sum_{k=0}^mf(k/m)(1/m)\to m\int_0^1f(x)dx$ then make the substitution I mentioned

Comment: no, you cant do that, because $$\lim_{m\to\infty} m\frac1m\sum_{k=0}^m f(k/m)\neq m\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac1m\sum_{k=0}^m f(k/m)$$

Comment: Ah I see maybe we can't take the limit but can we say they are approximately true for large m. Actually the approximation given in the book is $\sum_{k=0}^m\left(\frac{k}{m}\right)^n \approx \int_0^m\left(\frac{x}{m}\right)^n $. Can you tell me why this is true. I thought it would hold for general f.

Comment: if $f$ is positive and increasing then we have that $$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} f(k)\le\int_0^m f(x) dx\le\sum_{k=1}^m f(k)$$ The explanation can be seen [graphically](http://mathandmultimedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/geogebra18-4.png). In your case $$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}k^n\le\int_0^m k^n\le \sum_{k=0}^m k^n=\sum_{k=1}^m k^n$$ However the approximation is not as good as one can think, the larger $m$ the worse is the approximation

Comment: in my last comment by worse I mean that the absolute error gets bigger as $m$ increases, however the relative error doesn't have a prescribed way to be as $m$ increases. In the case that $f(x):=x^n$ because $f$ is convex then the relative error also increases as $m$ increases. By last note that $\sum (k/m)^n=\frac1{m^n}\sum k^n$ and that $\int (x/m)^n dx=\frac1{m^n}\int x^n dx$

Answer (score 1):

With one small change, this is just the right Riemann sum for a partition with all partition-widths $= 1$.

That is, the interval of integration is $[0,m]$ and the function being integrated is $g(x) := f\left(\frac xm\right)$, and we choose partition points $x_k = k, k = 0, ..., m$. On each partition $[k-1, k]$, we choose the right end point to be where we evaluate the function.

So we estimate the integral $$\int_0^m f\left(\frac xm\right)\,dx = \int_0^m g(x)\, dx \approx \sum_{k=1}^m g(k)[k - (k-1)] = \sum_{k=1}^m f\left(\frac km\right)$$

The difference from your formula is that the sum is from $k=1$, not $k = 0$. If $f(0) = 0$, the two sums agree, and note that the actual function they applied this to is indeed $0$ at $x = 0$.

Comment: If the partition widths are all 1, how does the approximation improve as m tends to infinity. Shouldn't the partition widths get smaller and smaller

Comment: @johnson - $m$ does not tend to infinity here. It is a fixed value. Riemann sums converge to the integral as their partition widths go to $0$, but $m$ does not have anything to do with partition widths in this approximation. $m$ is the width of the interval of integration. The only reason $m$ shows up as the upper limit of the summation is because when partition width is $1$, the number of partitions happens to be $\frac m 1 = m$. The calculation is approximating the integral with a particular Riemann sum. It is not calculating the actual value of the integral.